# Two ways of using offsets in memory addressing

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-registers, addressing-mode

For accessing arrays, I have the seen the following two notations used quite often:

```
# Addressing in the general form of: 
#  address_or_offset(%base_or_offset, %index, scale)

# (1) using a label, which resolves to an address
movzwq myarray(, %rdi, 2), %rbx           # 0x400078

# (2) using an offset based on a register, usually %rbp
movzwq -8(%rbp, %rdi, 2), %rcx
```

In the first form it uses the notation of `address(offset, index, scale)` and in the second it uses the notation of `offset(base, index, scale)`. My question is whether it is every practical to use the first notation with including an index register, something like:

```
movzwq myarray(%r11, %rdi, 2), %rbx
```

Of is that never used, and it's just always left blank (like in the first example) when using that `address(, index, scale)` notation?

Finally, is `offset/base` and `address/offset` just two ways of doing the same thing, that is, it allows arriving at start memory location by doing an offset from a register in the first case and from an address/label in the second case?

Comment: My answer on [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34058101) shows a hypothetical example of `mov al, [global_array + ecx + edx*2 + 10]` for indexing a 2D char array with 2 separate indices, if the row width happens to be small power of 2 you can do with the scale factor.  Or of course if you wanted to access `arr[i*5]`, you might use `arr(%rax, %rax, 4)` to do the math in the addressing mode.  It's not hard to come up with hypothetical examples where a compiler could and maybe would do that, try it on https://godbolt.org/

Comment: And yes, it doesn't matter how you got there, only what the final result of the address calculation is.  Like always in asm, multiple ways to implement high-level logic.  (Modulo some code-size and performance differences, like indexed addressing modes [being slower in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes/31027695#31027695), or [Is there a penalty when base+offset is in a different page than the base?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52351397) which only happens with `0..2047(%reg)` addressing modes, and only if the reg came from a load.)