# Is it more expensive to read a register or to read from memory?

Tags: x86, ram, cpu-registers

I was wondering: on the x86 architecture, does it take more time/CPU cycles to read a value from a register, or to read a value from RAM? I would assume RAM, since the CPU has to interface with an address/memory bus of some sort, whereas with a register it reads from a hardcoded area. Is this correct, or is there some other factor to take into account?

Comment: Look at compiler-generated asm.  It always uses registers when it can, not memory.  If the answer to this question wasn't obvious to you, go read https://agner.org/optimize/ and other performance links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.

Comment: Related: [Why are CPU registers fast to access?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3518445) - x86 is no exception to the rule that registers are even faster than L1d cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registers exist on the CPU, memory must be read from a chip over a bus.  So the register should always be faster.

Comment: L1d cache also exists inside each CPU core, but yes reading registers is even faster (lower latency, fewer uops), not having to go through a load port.  Note this is tagged x86, and all x86 CPUs have had caches for over 25 years.  (Not counting 8086-based microcontrollers.)

Comment: However, reading some special registers (like control registers, debug registers, or MSRs) can be slower.